# Will SQL Server Migration Assistant temporarily prevent database changes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access, database-migration

The e-commerce business I work for has been using Access until now to store all their data - and the main project I have been working on is migrating everything to use SQL Server instead. Right now I have set it up so that the data from new orders is being added to both the SQL Server and the Access database. So right now, the Access database consists of all of the actual orders, and the SQL Server database is a combination of test data and recent orders.

I plan on using SSMA to overwrite all of the data in the SQL Server to have a current copy of the Access database when we go live. The main issue is I wonder what will happen if somebody places an order in the 20 minute window that SSMA will be running - I imagine it will at least get added to the Access database (so I could look for differences between the two afterwards) - but will it also get added to the SQL Server? Will the requests go into a sort of queue and get processed when the SSMA operation is complete?

Comment: Can you not shut down for the change over?

Comment: Technically, we could - and it will probably only take about 20 minutes to migrate the Access database to the SQL Server based on how long it took me to do a test migration with the current data in the Access database. However, my boss would probably rather not shut down ordering for 20 minutes. Between midnight and 5 am there are usually only a few orders per hour, so perhaps that may be the best time to do it.